# Spring boot mapping static html

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, static-html

I want to create spring boot web application.

I have two static html files: one.html, two.html.

I want to map them as follows

```
localhost:8080/one
localhost:8080/two
```

without using template engines (Thymeleaf).

How to do that? I have tried many ways to do that, but I have 404 error or 500 error (Circular view path [one.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL).

OneController.java is:

```
@Controller
public class OneController {
    @RequestMapping("/one")
    public String one() {
        return "static/one.html";
    }
}
```

Project structure is

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please update your WebMvcConfig and include UrlBasedViewResolver and /static resource handler. Mine WebConfig class looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

I have checked it and seems working.

Maciej's answer is based on browser's redirect. My solution returns static without browser interaction.

Comment: Since Spring 5 WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is marked as Deprecated, so you need to implement the new interface WebMvcConfigurer !

Comment: I think the problem is that this resolver is global for all spring context, what about  I use thymeleaf or JSP and want to use a specific controller serving a static file?

Comment: Delete the "super.addResourceHandlers(registry)" upon implementing the WebMvcConfigurer. See the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393211/how-can-i-serve-static-html-from-spring-boot]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about additional browser redirect you can use this:

```
@Controller
public class OneController {
    @RequestMapping("/one")
    public String one() {
        return "redirect:/static/one.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I want to map all sub paths to the same file but keep the browser path as the original requested, at same time I use thymeleaf then I don't want to override it's resolver.

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @Value("${:classpath:/hawtio-static/index.html}")
    private Resource index;

    @GetMapping(value = {"/jmx/*", "/jvm/*"}, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity actions() throws IOException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new InputStreamResource(index.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

Obs. every hit will read the data from the index.html file, it will not be cached

Comment: `InputStreamResource` is not required. `ResponseEntity.ok(index)` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to spring along with thymeleaf and spent an hour trying to figure this out.

In your "application.properties" add

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```