# how to load static resources in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Having this `resources` layout in spring-boot app:

```
$ tree -L 2 resources/
resources/
├── application.properties
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   ├── scss
│   └── vendor
└── templates
    └── login.html
```

*login.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>SB Admin 2 - Login</title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link th:href="@{/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
    rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link th:href="@{/css/sb-admin-2.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Outer Row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="p-5">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Welcome Back!</h1>
                  </div>
                  <form class="user">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputEmail"
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword"
                        placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember
                          Me</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                      Login
                    </a>
                    <hr>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                      <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Login with Google
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Login with Facebook
                    </a>
                  </form>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="register.html">Create an Account!</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script th:src="@{/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js}"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script th:src="@{/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js}"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script th:src="@{/js/sb-admin-2.min.js}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

which is login from https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2 dash board, when running the spring boot app the css does not loads. Does thymeleaf knows about the folders is `static/`? This is firefox console:

```
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 6
Cookie “JSESSIONID” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite jquery.min.js
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/login” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
login
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js”. login:91:45
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/login” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
3 login
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js”. login:92:61
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/login” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
2 login
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js”. login:95:59
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/login” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
login
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/js/sb-admin-2.min.js”. login:98:38
```

Comment: If you use Spring Security, then you need to allow the CSS files already without authentication. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304578/static-web-resources-in-spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf